# How to properly display loading event on button click using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have three election contestant that I want to update their vote counts by making axios call to server backend.

Everything is working fine.

Here is an example of json response from axios call.

```
[{ "id": "1", "name": "contestant 1", "vote": "300" }]
```

**My Issue:**

My only issue is the loading event. When I click on first contestant to update its vote result via axios call. Instead
of the application to display **Content Loading...** only for the click contestant button, it will display **Content Loading...**
for all the three contestant button.

**What I want:**

Please how do I display **Content Loading...** only for the clicked contestant buttons

I guess this has to do with the Id of the clicked contestant. I have also tried this but no way

```
if (person.id === person_id){
this.setState({ loading: true });
}
```

**Here is the code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false,
 isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "contestant 1", vote: "3" },
        { id: "2", name: "contestant 2", vote: "6" },
        { id: "3", name: "contestant 3", vote: "2" }
      ]
    });
  }


  handleVote(person_id, person_vote) {
    const data_vote = {
      person_id: person_id,
      person_vote: person_vote
    };




this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {

 axios.get("http://localhost/apidb_react/result.json", { data_vote })
      .then(response => {
        const newData = this.state.data.map(person => {
       if (person.id !== person_id) return person;
       return { ...person,vote: response.data[0].vote };
        });
        this.setState(state => ({
          data: newData,
loading: false,
        }));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

});// close loading
  }

  render() {


let data_loading;
    if (this.state.loading) {
      data_loading = "Content Loading......"
    }


    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map(person => (
              <li key={person.id}>
                {person.name} --(vote count: {person.vote})
                <br />
{data_loading}
                <button
                  type="button"

                  onClick={() => this.handleVote(person.id, person.vote)}
                >  Get Vote</button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change data to `{ id: "1", name: "contestant 1", vote: "3", isLoading: false },` and then `{person.isLoading && "Content Loading.."}` instead of `{data_loading}`. You get the idea?

Comment: @FortyTwo that concept is not working. not showing any result. no error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a separate `loading` state for every contestant. So the logical next step would be to create Contestant component having it's own state and own UI for reflecting that state to the user.

Something like this:

```
class Contestant extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    onVote: () => {},
    onError: () => {}
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  handleVote(person_id, person_vote) {
    const data_vote = {
      person_id: person_id,
      person_vote: person_vote
    };

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/apidb_react/result.json", { data_vote })
      .then(response => {
        this.props.onVote(person_id, response.data[0].vote);
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.props.onError(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { person } = this.props;
    const { isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <li key={person.id}>
        {isLoading
          ? "Content Loading......"
          : `${person.name} --(vote count: ${person.vote})`}
        <br />
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => this.handleVote(person.id, person.vote)}
        >
          Get Vote
        </button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "contestant 1", vote: "3" },
        { id: "2", name: "contestant 2", vote: "6" },
        { id: "3", name: "contestant 3", vote: "2" }
      ]
    });
  }

  onVote = (person_id, vote) => {
    const { data } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      data: data.map(person => {
        if (person.id !== person_id) return person;
        return { ...person, vote };
      })
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map(person => (
              <Contestant
                key={person.id}
                person={person}
                onVote={this.onVote}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Somewhat functional sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/p7q3qylwj0. Obviously you will need to hit a real endpoint there, instead of:`http://localhost/apidb_react/result.json`

Comment: That is what  am still think on how to figure it out

Comment: Thanks Sir Jayarjo